# TrafficStats クラスを使用した通信量の取得とリセット

Tags: android, java, monitoring

現在パケット使用量を取得するアプリを作成しており、2点わからない個所がありました。この場をお借りして、質問させていただきます。

1. [`TrafficStats`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) のリセットについて

パケット量の取得を、以下の様な方法で取得しております。

```
TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()
```

日付が変更された際、 `TrafficStats` の情報をリセットしたいのですが、方法が見つかりませんでした。
`TrafficStats` の情報をリセットする方法は、ありますか？

2. `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)` について

各アプリ毎のパケット使用量は、`TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)` で取得しております。取得した値を見てみると、 WiFi の使用した通信も含まれているように感じます。 Mobile 通信だけ取得する方法は、ありませんか？

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最初のご質問だけ回答します。

> 1. TrafficStats のリセットについて

おっしゃる通り、Android ではリセットは難しい様です。通常の Linux OS であれば、NIC 用の kernel module を一旦 unload して再度 load する方法(`modprobe -r ... && modprobe ...`)があるのですが、Android の場合は再起動するしかないのかもしれません。  
面倒な方法になりますが、24時間置きに RX と TX の値を記録しておいて相対的な差分値を求める、というのが現実的かもしれませんね。

追記:

> 2. TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid) について

TrafficStats クラスのメソッドは基本的に `/proc/uid_stat/[uid]/..` や `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` などを読み込んで通信量を計算しています。これらのファイルを見ますと、個別の UID のレベルでは WiFi と Mobile 通信の通信量を分けていない様です。  
そこでざっと検索してみましたが、以下の記事が参考になるかもしれません。

[android statistic 3g traffic for each APP, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613402/android-statistic-3g-traffic-for-each-app-how)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
もう一度ロジックを考え直さないとだめみたいですね、、、
素早い回答ありがとうございました！
電源OFFの時、作り直されなきゃもっと楽なのに、、、